# What is the difference between consciousness and matter?

Tags: terminology, consciousness

I want to know the difference between consciousness, awareness, energy and matter. Also how could we define if any thing is consciousness or not?

Comment: Consciousness is something because of which you are able to be aware of your own existence in physical state.

Comment: Consciousness has self awareness, or "I". Matter doesn't.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between living beings and dead matter according to scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14520/277)

Answer (score 1):

Consciousness is awareness or witness.  It witnesses or is aware of the matter. But matter i.e. objects are not aware of the subject. (Consciousness). Anything which can be known or experienced are the objects (matter).

> **Form is the seen**, the eye is the seer; that eye is the seen, and mind
> is its seer; thoughts in the mind **are seen by the Witness, which alone
> is the Seer, but can never be the seen.**
>
> This (Witness) does not rise, nor does It set; It does not increase,
> nor does It decrease; **It shines by itself and then others does It
> illumine**, without any external aid. (Dṛg-Dṛśya-Viveka verses 1,5)