# Do Things And Objects Have A Soul Or Have A Jiva

Tags: rebirth, jiva

This is a dumb question, plz excuse that, I don’t understand so am asking. It’s easy to see how alive things have a soul, like a plant or tree, and I get that there is karma that made them be a tree or whatnot.

Sometimes while reading Hindu texts excerpts they say that even a rock has low level of soul too ? So a jiva/soul could be “born” as a rock ? But then how does it die or go to next birth ?

Does something like a mountain have a soul for sure, cause that story with Agastya and the mountain that blocked the sun for example. If a mountain or river has a soul, then a pebble or seashell would have one too ?

Also in modern times how does this work ? Like does a car have a soul ? Or does a house or table have a soul ? Does any machine have one ? Does each cell of your body have a soul as a micro-organism type stuffs ?

This sounds so dumb that I’m feeling like an idiot even typing out this question. I searched “soul” on here but like 211 pages of results so not sure if maybe this has already been asked on here. Thx !

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/what-is-the-difference-between-living-beings-and-dead-matter-according-to-script) is an answer from Vedānta perspective .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between living beings and dead matter according to scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/what-is-the-difference-between-living-beings-and-dead-matter-according-to-script)

Comment: Insentients , car , rock etc . lack cognitive faculties, -  can neither recognise its own existence , or its environment.(yet its existence is attributed to sat, being a part of sat chit ananda).Its insentient state  is consequential of (either  the absence or miniscule) of sattva quotient of panchabhutAs in them, (Only the sattva quotient can be the receptacle of consciousness). This is a topic is of Bhagavad Gita 7.5 , (also detailed in Panchadashi.)

Comment: Thx guys, really appreciate it. I deleted my earlier comments on both posts (cause they were kinda unclear and poorly written) but really appreciate hearing the the different viewpoints on this.

Comment: @Athrey Ji where can i learn (beginner lvl texts) about concepts of core Advaita like how it explains reincarnation/sentinent-insentinent beings etc??

Comment: Sir , Prakarana Granthas , (like Tattva bodha , Panchikaranam , Sarva vedanta Siddhanta Sara sangraha, Vivekachudamani, Panchadashi  etc) are the primer of Advaita Vedanta.
Shankara Bhagavadpada's Prakarana Granthas ,are in  simple Sanskrit, which  reflect only the content of Shruti(thus it simplified vedanta), and no new  idea or term is infused into it by Acharya. (Probably except for analogies). Venerable Swamiji's of Ramakrishna mutt ,(Swami Sivananda other institutions also),have provided English translation to  almost all advaitic works and made  it ,available for all.

Comment: In my understanding , sentiency is acquired by a jiva ,only thru its association of with its subtle body (sukshma shareer) . Here sukshma implies imperceivable. (Panchabhootas  without Panchikaranam are imperceivable( or sukshma) that make up the subtle body)  . Commentaries on  Bhagavad Gita , Upanishads(Prasthana Traya) affirms,/details reincarnation/rebirth.
All, Prakarana Grantha (PG)are  good to start with. If time allows,a read thru of the translation of Panchadashi ,(or any PG) wud throw light on the subject. @Rāmachandra

Comment: @Athrey Ji Thank you so so much for beautifully explaining my doubts and recommending me such an exhaustive list of scriptures! I would surely go through all of them step by step.Please accept my humble pranaam!

Comment: For anyone who comes across this thread later while browsing topics, I agree 100% w/ what Swami Vishwananda has written here in his answer and comment replies : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14655/atma-and-cells-in-the-body